# Macro that saves the file as macro-free closes the original file

Tags: vba, excel

Here is a snippet of the last part of a data manipulation macro:

```
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Dim fullfilenamelength As Integer, filenamelength As Integer
    fullfilenamelength = Len(ThisWorkbook.FullName)
    filenamelength = Len(udfWBFilename("ThisOne"))

    Dim newFilePath As String, newFileFullName As String
    newFilePath = Left(ThisWorkbook.FullName, fullfilenamelength - filenamelength)
    newFileFullName = newFilePath & "Aspects List.xlsx"

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=newFileFullName, FileFormat _
        :=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

    Workbooks.Open Filename:=newFileFullName
    Windows("Aspects List.xlsx").Activate

    Beep
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.StatusBar = False
End Sub
```

Here at the end, it saves the file as a macro-free workbook, then opens the new file.

Why does it close the old file when doing so?
(in other words, macro execution is stopped after running the line `Windows("Aspects List.xlsx").Activate` - the subsequent lines are never executed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove this line

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:=newFileFullName
```

After performing `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs`, your active workbook already refers to `Aspects List.xlsx`:

**Before `SaveAs`:**

[image]

**After `SaveAs`:**

[image]

Btw, it seems to me that

```
newFilePath = Left(ThisWorkbook.FullName, fullfilenamelength - filenamelength)
```

could be simplified to

```
newFilePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
```

Also it may be interesting: [How to avoid using Select/Active statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)